Vertex Group Weights missing from Viewport Overlays window
I'm trying to access the Vertex Group Weights overlay and it is missing from my viewports overlay window. My window looks like the first image. The second image is what it should look like. Is there something I need to enable in Preferences or something else going on please?
Thanks so much,
Maja



It won't be visible in Edit Mode unfortunately. You must go to Weight Paint mode

@MarkJackson That's not correct. The menu shown in the screenshot is from Edit Mode, in Weight Paint it is not called "Vertex Group Weights". And even if you see them as the same, both are no longer present in the Show Overlays menu in 4.x, they are now in their own separated dropdown menu right next to the Show Overlays menu (see moonboots' answer below).

In Blender 4, if you are in Edit mode, this display option is now in the Mesh Edit Mode Overlays panel:

If you are in Weight Paint mode it's now in the Weight Paint Overlays panel:


Thanks so much! I did have a look in the Mesh Edit Mode overlays, but couldn't see it due to the grey colour scheme. The grey to me registers as unavailable. Still getting used to Blender
